# Getting null when converting const char* to NSString Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to convert a const char* that I'm getting from a C++ method that I have, to a NSString in a method in Objective-C. This is the method from c++:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
EXPORT
string getAudioWmark(const char* _filename)
{
    string filename = string(_filename);
    string result;
    result = get_watermark(filename, "");
    
    return (result.c_str());
}
```

This is what result is returning in the debugger view:

```
result  std::string "pattern  0:00 f59e26b2f4668d02bd33e03a1c0d8892 0.774 0.774 CLIP-A\n\n"
```

This is the declaration of the method in the .h file from Objective-C:

```
extern const char* getAudioWmark(const char* filename);

@interface WatermarkLib : NSObject

- (void)getAudio:(NSString*)filename;

@end
```

And this is the .mm implementation of the method:

```
- (void)getAudio:(NSString*)filename {
    
    const char *cString = [filename cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString* externalString = [NSString stringWithCString:getAudioWmark(cString) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"Exito! %@", externalString);
}
```

"externalString" is null, and that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: The declaration of `getAudioWmark` does not match the definition.  `string getAudioWmark(const char* _filename)` does not match `const char* getAudioWmark(const char* filename)`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Your `getAudioWmark` returns a `std::string`, but your objective-c code is casting that to a `NSString`.  Those aren't the same thing.  I've not used objective C, so not sure what fix you need but the C++ code may need to just return a `const char*` instead of an `string`

Comment: Correcting the function prototype won’t help by itself. It’s illegal to access the `c_str` of a destructed `std::string`(which it will be when that helper function returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you out.

```
const char *cString = filename.UTF8String;
```

But make sure filename has content otherwise it must result in null